# Unity use Transform Find the name as same as parent name return null in unity player

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject

In my Hierarchy, I have a gameobject like this `GameObject/GameObject`, the parent and child nodes have the same name. i want get the child gameobject, i used the flowing code:

```
 GameObject parent = GameObject.Find("GameObject");
 Transform childTransform = parent.transform.Find("GameObject");
```

this code work well in unity Editor, but when i build it out, the `childTransform`  is `null`, why? I'm confused about it.

Does anyone know why

Comment: I just tested it and it correct works.

Answer (score 0):

`GameObject.Find` does not guarantee anything about the search traversal order. Thus in build, it might search differently, for reasons that are not exposed to users.

`GameObject.Find`, however, does support path-like names, so you access the child like this:

```cs
GameObject.Find("path/to/parent/GameObject/GameObject")
```

If that is not enough, you will have to resort to a manual traversal of the hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, the `GameObject.Find` search traversal order does not consistent in different environments. But I don't see any explanation in the official documentation, So I want to ask for help who knows the details, is this an intrinsic feature of Unity3D or a bug.   I also found that when I set a `Tag` on the child node, use the `GameObject.Find("parentname")`,  the return `gameobject .scenePath` is `GameObject/GameObject`

Comment: It is neither a feature nor a bug, it is merely a missing guarantee. You will encounter this all the time especially in performance-critical cross-platform frameworks. There are no interesting "details" to be considered here. Even if you looked at the source code and knew exactly what was going on under the hood, it would be bad practice to act upon it.

Comment: Ok, I'm understand it, Thank you very much. @One Full Time Equivalent

Answer (score 0):

You just don't need to find all the objects with `GameObject.Find`, use `GetChild`.

```cs
var parent = GameObject.Find("GameObject");

if (parent.transform.childCount > 0)
{
    var childTransform = parent.transform.GetChild(0);
    
    Debug.Log(childTransform); // child name..
}
```

Comment: clearly, this may have the same issue that OP had in the build: the name is not unique and you might pick up the child directly with `Find`.

Comment: @OneFullTimeEquivalent There are two issues here, first, that Find is not a good way to reference, and second, that as OP says, child is null in build, that is, find takes the parent object.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned above `parent.transform.childCount` is `0`. Of course, Of course, the official documentation advises does not use `GameObject.Find` this method, but I'm just curious about the problem I found.